# How to save a string to Core Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm creating a signup form with multiple view controllers as "pages" and I need the information from one view controller such as 'First name' and 'last name' or 'email address' to another view controller. I decided I'm going to use core data to save the strings and retrieve them from another view controller rather than create a global struct for every view controller (because it crashes every time I try and implement it). Heres my code:

```
@IBAction func nextBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if firstNameText.text != "" && lastNameText.text != "" {
            //Core Data User Information
            var userInfo = UserInfo() // The Name of the Core Data Entity
            var firstName: String = firstNameText.text!
            userInfo.firstName = firstName

            do {
            try NSManagedObjectContext.save(firstName)//Need Fixing
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toBirthdate", sender: self)
    } else {
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
    }
}
```

Here is the error log : `'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UserInfo setFirstName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001530e80'`
Full error log: [View Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w36tnoyz27w21d8/Untitled%20document.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first I was going to give the obvious answer which is that, in your Core Data data model, your `UserInfo` entity does not have a `firstName` attribute.

That's still possible, but then I looked at the full transcript you posted and saw that, a couple hundred microseconds before this error is another error:

```
Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'UserInfo'
```

I suspect this error indicates that you have initialized your managed object with `init()`.  This is a common mistake of first-time Core Data users.  Ensure that you are initializing your `UserInfo` object like this:

```
let userInfo  = UserInfo.init(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: context);
```

or if your deployment target is iOS 10 or later, you can use the newer cleaner method:

```
let userInfo  = UserInfo.init(context: context)
```

Comment: My `UserInfo` entity has a `firstName` attribute. I am very new to core data and cannot find a video that explains enough to where I am successful at completing it. I tried to do `let userInfo = UserInfo.init(context: context)`. However, I got a error saying `Use of unresolved identifier 'context'; did you mean 'connect'?` But even If I change context to connect, I still get an error.

Comment: I did mean `context`.  It is a symbol name, referencing the managed object context in which you wish to insert your new object.  In any Core Data project, you must have at least one managed object context.  Assuming you created a new iOS – Swift – Core Data project in Xcode 10, you will see in AppDelegate.swift line 79 `let context = persistentContainer.viewContext`.  That is your "main queue" managed object context and it should work.

Comment: Learning Core Data by *trial and error* is not efficient.  I think you would benefit by spending at least an hour reading about it.  Sadly, Apple is no longer maintaining its [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1), but at this date it's still correct enough to get started.  The first page, *What is Core Data* scares people off.  Try to roll through it.  Or you could find a Core Data book or tutorial from Ray Wenderlich or whatever.